# How to extract a substring value from Json response in SOAPUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to fetch the requestID from the message which is a string.

```
{
   "version": "1.0.0-80",
   "status": 201,
   "error": "MSG004",
   "uuid": "aae1bb59-da3f-4118-a4a4-asdfsdfsd",
   "message": "Successfully created a request with an id of 1234",
   "path": "/api/request/",
   "timestamp": "2019-03-21T09:41:58.484"
}
```

Can anyone help me with creating a property from message, I only need to pass request id in the end of this sentence:

"Successfully created a request with an id of 1234"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a straight-forward substring should do the trick.

```
def id = variableThatContainsTheString.substring(46)
```

This however is not pretty. But nor is the solution you are testing.

I would argue that if the ID is something that should be used by the consumer of the webservice, then it really should be delivered in a key-value of its own. There should be no need to cut it from a string.

The response could then be something like this:

```
{ 
  "version": "1.0.0-80",
  "status": 201, 
  "error": "MSG004", 
  "uuid": "aae1bb59-da3f-4118-a4a4-asdfsdfsd", 
  "message": "Successfully created a request with an id of 1234", 
  "path": "/api/request/", 
  "timestamp": "2019-03-21T09:41:58.484",
  "id": "1234" 
}
```

Tell the developers to get their act together. ;-)

Comment: I hope this is enough of a response. If you are stumped already at fetching the name-value-pairs, I suggest you take a look at JsonSlurper.

Comment: Thank you Steen, that ID is not used by the consumer. i am just using it for myself.